# jQuery 1.8.3 ajax jsonp does not return any response or statusCode with wrong URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am not getting any type of response/callback/event from a jQuery 1.8.3 ajax jsonp Call made to an invalid URL which does not exists (error 500) or that is not found (error 404).
I am never getting back any type of answer neither in the common success or error callbacks nor in the other ajax response methods.

**Using jQuery 1.8.3**. Maybe the fix for this issue was patched later.
With 1.9+ or 1.11 seems it is also not working.

What could be wrong in the following code or how should it be done?

https://jsfiddle.net/q9Lcso37/

Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://invalidUrl/--invalid--' + '?callback=?',
    data: '',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (result) {
        alert("callback success.");
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("callback error.");
    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert("error 404, not found.");
        },
        500: function() {
            alert("error 500, invalid url.");
        }
    }
})
.done(function() {
    alert("done success");
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("fail error");
})
.always(function() {
    alert("always complete");
});
```

Comment: your xhr from console what status code has it got ?

Comment: In the browser console I get a not found error: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)',  or a invalid url error 500.

Comment: madalin forgot to put the jQuery version. I am using 1.8.3, maybe a fix was released in new versions.

Comment: Also tested with 1.11 but doesnt seem to work: GET https://invalidurl/--invalid--?callback=jQuery1110030151252751238644_1457001736001&_=1457001736002 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVEDsend @ jquery-1.11.0.js:9838jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.0.js:9211(anonymous function) @ (index):47jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.11.0.js:4624elemData.handle @ jquery-1.11.0.js:4292